# Is it possible to tell rsync to abort if the source directory is empty?

Tags: linux, rsync

I want to prevent situations where the source filesystem is temporarily unmounted when I run

```
rsync -av --delete $source $target
```

It seems that if I could tell `rsync` to refuse to work on an empty source directory, that would do the trick.  I don't see any obvious flags or combinations of flags that would do that, though.  Note that, in general, the source is remote, so it's a little harder to tell if it's empty.

How to deal with this problem?

Comment: Why is it harder to tell if the source is empty? `test -s "/whatever/path"` should return a relevant exit status. No?

Comment: In the case of a remote machine, it would be something like: ssh remote.host "test -s /whatever/path"

Comment: Or test of it's a mount point directly, with `mountpoint -q`... If not, then the filesystem isn't mounted.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a login shell on the remote host (and that the remote shell is `bash`), use the shell built-in `compgen` to test whether the source directory is empty.

First, ensure that your `$source` variable does not include a hostname.  Instead, let the hostname be `$remote_host`.

```
if ssh $remote_host "compgen -G $source/*" | grep -q '^'
then
    rsync -av --delete $remote_host:$source $target
else
    printf "Directory %s is empty on host %s\n" "$source" "$remote_host"
fi
```

One could perhaps simply `compgen -G $source/* > /dev/null` but since one match is sufficient to prove non-emptiness, I'm hoping that piping to `grep -q` will be faster in the case where there could be a large number of entries that match the glob.